# adding javascript variable to actionlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have AJAX request that looks like this:

```
jsonData = JSON.stringify({stuff: stuff});
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%=Url.Action("myMethod", "myController") %>',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: jsonData,
            success: function (data) {
            $("#myDiv").append('<span><%=Html.ActionLink("Details", "myMethod", new {id      = data.id })%></span>');
         }
)};
```

**EDIT! I am trying to append this Actionlink to a div on "success". I somehow forgot the $("#myDiv").append() code during my initial post.**

In the `new {id = data.id }` section, I'd like to use the data.id (a javascript variable) in this actionlink.

I keep getting errors saying either data is not defined, or too many characters in literal, etc..

Has anyone successfully done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly do it, since one part of the code is run at the server (*the `Url.Action` part*) and the `data.id` is only available once the code reaches the client browser..

But you could do a trick to it like set the `id` from server to have a dummy unique value, and replace it with javascript..

```
$("#myDiv")
   .append('<span><%=Html.ActionLink("Details", "myMethod", new {id = "-dummy-"})%></span>'.replace('-dummy-',data.id));
```

Answer (score 2):

Sir I think you confused between server side (<%) tags and cliend side execution context. `"data"` is a variable defined in the client side and everything between those server side tags will be processed on the server. There is no variable in your page named `"data"`! cause you want to use it in the server and it's between server side (<% %>) tags.

In the client your script would be something like the code below:

```
jsonData = JSON.stringify({stuff: stuff});
        $.ajax({
            url: 'THE_PROCESSED_RESULT_OF_SERVER_TAG_GOES_HERE',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: jsonData,
            success: function (data) {
    '<span>THE_PROCESSED_RESULT_OF_SERVER_TAG_GOES_HERE</span>'
         }
)};
```

Check the file contents with developer tools (or any other things), you will see what is actually happening in the client.

**UPDATE**

Again! you can't do such a thing as I already mentioned. There is a difference between server side code and client side code. No matter how you want to access the variable named `"data"`. It does not defined in the server side code. It's the parameter of success function which will be executed in the client side execution context.

Hope it helps
Cheers

Comment: Also dumping a span tag in the succes function does not do anything eitehr

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you for mentioning that. Yeah, absolutly right.

Comment: I'm sorry, Take a look at the post again. I'm trying to append the actionresult link to a div on success.

My fault. The first post omitted the append code.

Comment: Again it makes no difference. See the updated answer. Hope it helps. And also see the answer of @karaxuna. I think it is what you are looking for. Cheers

Comment: So you would need to append to something

Comment: I think @karaxuna 's answer has something to say. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

```
'<span><a href="<%=Url.Action("Details", "myMethod")%>?id=' + data.id + '"></a></span>'
```

Comment: `id` might be a required route parameter, and if so the `Url.Action` will fail without it..